# Core Data - Quiz query - Recording progress?

Tags: ios, core-data, entity

I am coding a quiz game for iOS/Swift using Core Data.

I have the following entities as per diagram

[image: quiz entities]

A `Challenge` has many `Questions`
IE: Easy has 10 questions

Where I'm stuck is one feature I'm trying to build:

1. Challenge completion progress
   Keep a record of all questions already answered for a given challenge, and current score.

IE: Tom has completed 3/10 questions from the "easy" challenge and has a score of "300"

Question: How do I model quiz completion progress in Core data?

I'm thinking I need another Entity called `PlayerAnswers` but not sure what fields need to be in there to record the correct information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You modelled objects for storing general representation of Challenge. Now you need to add table that will contains challenges progress. If challenge questions immutable a simplest one will contains. it's ok if user can't skip questions in one challenge

**playerId | challlengeId | challengeProgress | challengeScore**

If you need each question state and overall score for challenge you will need to store all users answers like this (in terms of SQL tables)

table 1      **gameId | playerId | challlengeId**
where gameId represents user attempt if he can have several attemps for one challenge

table 2      **gameId | answer | isCorrect | score**

this table stores all answers for all games. And we can fetch answers with their state for needed gameId

So in this case in terms of core data you need to add 2 entities: Game which have one to one connection to User and Challenge and Answer which have one to many connection from the Game